# Upgrading Drush 6 to Drush 9 on Centos 5 server

Tags: upgrading, drush

I haven't updated drush in awhile and looking to update it to the latest. I'm not exactly sure how it was installed originally. But when I do a **which drush**, it shows it resides in **/usr/bin/drush**

When I do a **drush dl drush** - I only get the option to upgrade to 7.x only.

How can I update it to Drush 9?

Can I just do a git clone of the drush repo from: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush

Then do I just do a checkout of the drush 9 tag? But how do I make it the default drush application to run? Or do I just overwrite the file in /usr/bin/drush?

FYI: My linux server admin skills aren't up to par.

Comment: What version of PHP is on your server?  CentOS 5 only supports old versions, even with the IOS repos.  You may not be able to get a recent version of drush to work.

Comment: I just got the server guys to upgrade it to 5.5.23 -- would I run into any issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drush dl drush` downloads the obsolete version of Drush from drupal.org. Drush was never intended to be used to download Drush via the pm-download command, even when it was hosted on drupal.org; the fact that this works is more of an anomaly or coincidence than design.

To update to a newer Drush, follow the usual [instructions in the Drush documentation](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/).  Since you already have Drush in `usr/bin/drush`, use this location instead of the location stipulated in the docs (`usr/local/bin/drush`).

```
wget http://files.drush.org/drush.phar
chmod +x drush.phar
sudo mv drush.phar /usr/bin/drush
```

The Drush at files.drush.org/drush.phar is always the most recent stable version of Drush. To download a specific version, visit https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases. There is a phar available with every release of Drush from version 8 and later.  You can, of course, replace your /usr/bin/drush at any time that you need to upgrade.

Comment: what if i wanted to update it in the future? do i do the same thing? thanks greg!

Comment: I'm actually getting a weird error after doing the upgrade like you said: http://prntscr.com/aygq6d --- when i run drush, it just says **X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.28** did i download the wrong one?

Comment: Very weird, but it works when I'm not logged in as root. Any idea to why that is?

Comment: Symptom looks like you are running php-cgi instead of php-cli. Your $PATH is probably different as root. Probably best to always do php development as a non-root user anyway.

Comment: where would i make this change from cgi to cli? i checked php.ini and there's no reference to change that. sorry that my command line-fu isn't all that great. thanks greg!

Comment: nevermind i did a **which php** and then went to /usr/bin and saw that there was a **php-cli** and just replaced that with the **php** binary

Comment: Be careful about swapping out php binaries; you wouldn't want to use php-cli with your webserver.

Comment: =D ... just found that out the hard way.. yea my site just died because i did that. i switched it back and its working now. not sure how to make php-cli run as default when using drush.

Comment: Probably the simplest way would be to symlink /usr/bin/php-cli to ~/bin/php, and make sure that ~/bin is in your $PATH ahead of /usr/bin when you're logged in to your shell.

Comment: I take Drush 9 is the master branch. Isn't a little too early to install it?

Comment: Yes, good point. I have actually answered how to install Drush 8 here, missing that detail from the subject line. Drush 9 is, in fact the `master` branch of Drush. It was only recently forked, and is currently very similar to Drush 8 at the time of this writing. Folks will soon be in for a bumpy ride if they install it. Dev versions of Drush are generally usable (the maintainers all use HEAD of master for day-to-day work), but behavior can change without warning when you are on dev.